# Specifics of implementing custom delegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use my own delegate methods. i follow the [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) .but is it must to use the class in which i have declared delegate method(protocol definition)  for calling that delegate method?cant i call without creating the object for the class in which  i have  protocol definition? what is the use of  the method  "delegate respondsToSelector:@selector"…?any help pls.?

Answer (score 1):

> what is the use of the method
>   "delegate
>   respondsToSelector:@selector"…?

In objective-c you can send any message to any object, BUT if object can't respond to it then your program may crash - so if you're not sure if certain object responds to some selector then you can (and should) check that in run-time using `respondsToSelector:` method - it can save you from a lot of troubles.

You don't have to declare protocols as well but they are a good way to make sure that objects of some type respond to selector in compile-time.

Comment: That's truth, I have also an explanation on simple protocol usage here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322562/what-is-the-best-way-for-a-view-added-via-presentmodalviewcontroller-to-communica/3323043#3323043

Answer (score 0):

Also see Apple's [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html), which discusses delegates, protocols, and selectors. Though its listed under Mac OS X, most (if not all) appears to apply to iOS also.